# Counter example to theorem : Every ideal of a ring $R$ is the kernel of a ring homomorphism of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

**Theorem** : every ideal of a ring R is the kernel of a ring homomorphism of R.

I came up with an example that this is not true. We know that $\phi: Z \to Z_9$ is a homomorphism that maps $k \to k$ mod 9. We also have $2Z$ as an ideal for Z. But clearly, $\phi(2) \neq 0$. I found the theorem from the book *Contemporary Abstract Algebra* by Joseph A. Gallian.

Comment: It seems like only kernel for this homomorphism is all the integer multiples of 9.

Comment: Well, $2\mathbb{Z}$ isn't the kernel of the ring homomorphism $\phi \colon \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_9$. But maybe there is a different ring homomorphism $\psi$ whose kernel it is?

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you, I think I understood it now. So, it's not necessarily true for all ideals of a ring with certain homomorphism have to be the kernels. But every ideal in a ring is a kernel for some homomorphism of the ring?

Comment: Pretty much. For every ring homomorphism $h \colon R_1 \to R_2$, its kernel is an ideal of $R_1$. Typically, $R_1$ has many other ideals. On the other hand, if $I$ is a (two-sided) ideal of a ring $R$, then $I$ is the kernel of the canonical homomorphism $\pi \colon R \to R/I$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You confuse the statements. It is not

> Every ideal is the kernel of any homomorphism

But rather

> Every ideal is the kernel of some homomorphism

The latter says there exist at least one homomorphism having the ideal as its kernel, which is true. The former says every ideal would be the kernel of a given homomorphism, which is false.